rouble Exporting Values from Discord.js Interaction: Why is 'report' Returning Undefined
Oke i have exported all my data from report.js:
`        const userId = interaction.options.getString('userid'); const userName = interaction.options.getString('username'); const serverName = interaction.options.getString('servername'); const reden = interaction.options.getString('reden'); const type = interaction.options.getString('type'); const links = interaction.options.getString('links');
    const Idata = {
        userId: userId,
        userName: userName,
        reden: reden,
        type: type,
        links: links
    }

   exports.Idata = Idata`

Then in bot.js i have this code:
const report = require("../commands/db/Report") +
`client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
if (interaction.customId !== 'btn_aanvaard') return;
console.log(report.Idata.userId)
const schema = require('../db_models/addMember')
let channelID;
const type = report.Idata.type
if (type === 'Leakers') {
    channelID = '1230232443592769676';
} else if (type === 'Raiders') {
    channelID = '1230232747935666196';
} else if (type === 'Scammers') {
    channelID = '1230233075544232050';
} else if (type === 'Servers') {
    channelID = '1230233415710806139';
} else if (type === 'Overig') {
    channelID = '1230233221438898286';
}
const TreatChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID)
        const newUser = new schema({
            userId: report.Idata.userId,
            userName: report.Idata.userName,
            reden: report.Idata.reden,
            type: report.Idata.type,
            bewijslink: [report.Idata.links]
        });
        await TreatChannel.threads.create({
            name: report.Idata.userName,
            reason: report.Idata.reden,
            message: `
    >  -  Dossier ${report.Idata.userName}


    > ✨Discord gebruikersnaam: ${report.Idata.userName}
    > ‍ Discord gebruiker discord id: ${report.Idata.userId}
    >  Reden: ${report.Idata.reden}
    >  Bewijs: ${[report.Idata.Eventslinks]}

    *Heeft u meer informatie over dit persoon? Maak dan snel een ticket aan!* `
        })

        newUser.save()
            .then(async user => {
                interaction.user.send(`Uw report (${report.Idata.userName}) is geaccepteerd door 1 van onze staff leden! De persoon is toegevoegd aan onze database`)
                await interaction.channel.delete()
            })

})`
why do i get this error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userId')
I have tryd moduele.exports
